# Inserting into MongoDB using Spring Data inserts into two Collections

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, groovy, spring-data-mongodb

I'm creating a Spring Boot application that is inserting objects into a MongoDB database. The problem is that when I'm doing the insert it is creating records in two collections. Basically I have a POJO A and POJO B that extends A. When the insert happens it creates documents in both collection A and collection B for the same ObjectId. My expectation was that it would only create documents in collection B for POJO B as that is what is being passed into the repository.insert method. What am I doing wrong? I can provide configurations and version numbers if needed. Also, I am using Groovy if that makes a difference.

Comment: Do you have a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at hand to look at? Generally speaking, the target collection is determined from the given type. Have you tried `@Document("your desired target collection name here")` on the root entity (POJO A)?

Comment: @ChristophStrobl I'll add one when I have some time in the next two days.

Comment: @ChristophStrobl I think I figured out my issue due to your urging me to build an example. I created a demo app and it exhibited the behavior that I was expecting. My original app is using batch processing with a MongoWriter and converting the class in the processor therefore the writer is treating it differently and creating the new collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was based on my application and therefore an issue that I introduced. I'm using Spring Batch and using the MongoReader and MongoWriter. I'm reading from collection "a" and I expected the writer to write back to collection "a" but inside of the processor I'm converting the object to POJO B and because I'm not specifying the collection then the MongoWriter determines the collection based on the class and creates collection "b". I added the same Document annotation to both classes and that resolved the issue.